# MySQL Insert into table fail

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am working on a live system which I tried two days ago, I re-designed it, but now the posts aren't inserted into the MySQL table. Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","h26them_live","tpcadmin","h26them_live");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }    
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO posts (location, post, date, by) VALUES('$post_location', '$post_field', '$date', '$by')");
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log? What errors do you get? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

You should report on errors from inserts, but `by` is a reserved word in MySQL.  You need surround it with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO posts (location, post, date, `by`)
```

It's good that you're using mysqli over mysql, but your code is still vulnerable because your queries aren't parameterized.